# Problem in loading spatial files into MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, shapefile

I want to load shape files in mysql,i right clicked on schema->load spatial data-> path selected ->[image] next-> here i am getting no columns[image]. Please can any one suggest something.

I have tried different EPSGs
and set my Charset to UTF-8